# Calendar issue with 000Z time zone

Tags: java, calendar, dozer

I'm having a weird situation with Java Calendar. I'm using dozer mapper to map the objects.

My requirenment is that I got an XML schema element that accepts only a Calendar type,

say element `<expDtTime>2010-11-11T09:30:47.000Z</expDtTime>`

I have to convert this. I wrote the following converter:

```
public Calender m(Date source,Calender c) {
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
calendar.setTime(source);
return calendar;
}
```

I need it in the same format. But it is showing as

```
<expDtTime>2010-11-11T04:00:47.000Z</expDtTime>
```

I want my object to have same format and value. It is showing 4:00 for time.

Is there any way to get rid of this problem?

Any suggestions or help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "it is showing as"? It's very unclear exactly what you're doing. Note that "000Z" is not the time zone here - the 000 is just saying "no milliseconds" and "Z" is for UTC as the time zone. (Or at least, "no offset from UTC at this instant".

Comment: yes don't change the timezone. Is your system timezone GMT?

Answer (score 0):

For manipulations with XML dateTime use XMLGregorianCalendar from javax.xml.datatype package.

parse from string

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xgc = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar("2010-11-11T04:00:47.000Z");
GregorianCalendar gc = xgc.toGregorianCalendar();
```

convert from GregorianCalendar

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xgc = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);
```

format to XML dateType string

```
 String xmlDate = xgc.toString();
```

Comment: I'm using dozer mapper to map the objects. I'm using Junit to test this. My actual and expected should be same. <expDtTime>2010-11-11T09:30:47.000Z</expDtTime> is a Date object. newXMLGregorianCalendar() takes a String. Tried to convert it throwing illigelArgumentException